# node.js 6.0.0 buffer to string equivalent in python3

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, applepay

I'm converting an old node.js lib into python and can't reproduce the behaviour of Buffer.toString() in python.

[this lib](https://github.com/samcorcos/apple-pay-decrypt/tree/5f2557bb0ea0afc0ecf43ce961047490979a0e3c) is use in a **node 6.0.0** environment

I did take a look at [this node issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12908), but i don't understand if it's linked to my problem.

js function:

```js
const KDF_PARTY_V = Buffer.from('E6F8C08930597B47472620568D207A23E4FCEF4B3F0AA3DC26FF369C622C6E1D', 'hex').toString('binary') 
// The SHA-256 hash of your ID string literal; 32 bytes in size.
console.log(KDF_PARTY_V)
```

output:

```
æøÀ0Y{GG& V z#äüïK?
£Ü&ÿ6b,n
```

python equivalent:

```py
kdf_v = memoryview(bytes.fromhex('E6F8C08930597B47472620568D207A23E4FCEF4B3F0AA3DC26FF369C622C6E1D')).tobytes().decode('latin-1')
print(kdf_v)
```

the output (badly shown by stack)

```
æøÀ‰0Y{GG& V z#äüïK?
£Ü&ÿ6œb,n
```

My actual console message:
[image]
maybe i sould use something different than latin-1 and utf-8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just a console caracter encoding mistake

when looking at the binary data itself the python version is the same as the js one so:

```py
kdf_v = bytes.fromhex(merchant_id).decode('latin1')
```

work perfectly

@AKX i do need to have the variable in str format, because i use it in a concatenation and the result of it in a sha256 digest

Answer (score 0):

Just don't try to `decode` at all. Decoding turns bytestrings into text strings, and a hash isn't a text string.

```
kdf_v = bytes.fromhex('E6F8C08930597B47472620568D207A23E4FCEF4B3F0AA3DC26FF369C622C6E1D')
```

gives you a 32-byte `bytes` object, which is functionally equivalent to a Node.js `Buffer`.